# Read text of dynamic object in Watir

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I'm trying to select and print the text of a dynamic object in Watir. Each time the object is generated, it is a random string. Not sure quite how to point to the object.

```
<dd itemprop="trait">
text
</dd>
```

I tried using xpath and pointing to the itemprop attribute, but the program just errors out when I run it. Not sure if this is impossible with xpath or if my code is simply incorrect.

```
def read_dd_itemprop(trait)
    itemprop_text = @@browser.element(:xpath, "//dd[@itemprop='" + trait + "')]").text
    p itemprop_text
end
```

Stacktrace:

```
  The given selector //dd[@itemprop='trait')] is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
  InvalidSelectorError: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //dd[@itemprop='trait')] because of the following error:
  [Exception... "The expression is not a legal expression."  code: "12" nsresult: "0x805b0033 (SyntaxError)"  location: "file:///var/folders/bv/4z13hkpn095bytggxzrx4l9h0000gp/T/webdriver-profile20130715-7256-ihkq92/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js Line: 5773"] (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::InvalidSelectorError)
  [remote server] file:///var/folders/bv/4z13hkpn095bytggxzrx4l9h0000gp/T/webdriver-profile20130715-7256-ihkq92/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8379:in `FirefoxDriver.annotateInvalidSelectorError_'
  [remote server] file:///var/folders/bv/4z13hkpn095bytggxzrx4l9h0000gp/T/webdriver-profile20130715-7256-ihkq92/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8410:in `FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElementInternal_'
  [remote server] file:///var/folders/bv/4z13hkpn095bytggxzrx4l9h0000gp/T/webdriver-profile20130715-7256-ihkq92/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver_component.js:8414:in `FirefoxDriver.prototype.findElement'
  [remote server] file:///var/folders/bv/4z13hkpn095bytggxzrx4l9h0000gp/T/webdriver-profile20130715-7256-ihkq92/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10421:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_/h'
  [remote server] file:///var/folders/bv/4z13hkpn095bytggxzrx4l9h0000gp/T/webdriver-profile20130715-7256-ihkq92/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/command_processor.js:10426:in `DelayedCommand.prototype.executeInternal_'
```

Am I close? is this a reasonable approach, or should I take a different angle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra bracket ")".

```
itemprop_text = @@browser.element(:xpath, "//dd[@itemprop='" + object + "']").text
```

Also note that, I was expecting xpath to be `//dd[@itemprop='the value of object']`, rather than `//dd[@itemprop='object']`. Please check if you `object`'s value is correct, for example, should be "trait".

Comment: It was pointing to the trait, I did a crappy job of editing the stack trace appropriately as I am a bit sleep deprived right now. Which was also likely the source of this error, as that fix worked perfectly. Thanks.